# how to count characters in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, character

I created a function that would count the number of characters in a string with this code:

```
def count_characters_in_string(mystring):
    s=0
    x=mystring
    for i in x:
        t=i.split()
        s=s+len(t)            
        print("The number of characters in this string is:",s)

count_characters_in_string("Apple")
```

This is what it returns:
The number of characters in this string is: 1
The number of characters in this string is: 2
The number of characters in this string is: 3
The number of characters in this string is: 4
The number of characters in this string is: 5

Is there a way to only print the last line so that it prints:

The number of characters in this string is: 5

Comment: Why not just use len("Apple")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
def count_characters_in_string(input_string)

    letter_count = 0

    for char in input_string:
        if char.isalpha():
            letter_count += 1

    print("The number of characters in this string is:", letter_count)
```

When you run:

```
count_characters_in_string("Apple Banana")
```

It'll output:

```
"The number of characters in this string is: 11"
```

Comment: You are right, but now it also counts white spaces which it didn't previously

Answer (score 3):

you can just use:

```
len(mystring)
```

in your code, to print only the last line you can use:

```
for i in x:
    s += 1          
print("The number of characters in this string is:",s)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python string can be seen as a list u can just take its lenght

```
def count_characters_in_string(word):
    return len(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
def count_characters_in_string(mystring):
    s=0
    x=mystring
    for i in x:
        t=i.split()
        s=s+len(t)            
    print("The number of characters in this string is:",s)

count_characters_in_string("Apple")
```